# TWA - Notification Delegation Service not working

Tags: android, google-chrome, trusted-web-activity

We are using trusted web activity for our app and we are getting chrome notifications instead it should come from trusted web activity delegation service.
If there is something wrong in following code please help me.

We have custom splash screen activity from there we launch trusted web activity, Is it happening because of this?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:manageSpaceActivity="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.ManageDataLauncherActivity"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/assetStatements" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="web_manifest_url"
            android:value="@string/webManifestUrl" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="twa_generator"
            android:value="@string/generatorApp" />

        <activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.ManageDataLauncherActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.MANAGE_SPACE_URL"
                android:value="@string/launchUrl" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LauncherActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/launcherName">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DEFAULT_URL"
                android:value="@string/launchUrl" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.STATUS_BAR_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/navigationColor" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_COLOR_DARK"
                android:resource="@color/navigationColorDark" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="androix.browser.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_DIVIDER_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/navigationDividerColor" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="androix.browser.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_DIVIDER_COLOR_DARK"
                android:resource="@color/navigationDividerColorDark" />
             <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_IMAGE_DRAWABLE"
             android:resource="@drawable/tes_logo" />
             <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_SCREEN_BACKGROUND_COLOR"
             android:resource="@color/backgroundColor" />
             <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_SCREEN_FADE_OUT_DURATION"
             android:value="@integer/splashScreenFadeOutDuration" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY"
                android:value="@string/providerAuthority" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.FALLBACK_STRATEGY"
                android:value="@string/fallbackType" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SCREEN_ORIENTATION"
                android:value="@string/orientation" />
            
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.FocusActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.WebViewFallbackActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/providerAuthority"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>

        <service
            android:name=".DelegationService"
            android:enabled="@bool/enableNotification"
            android:exported="@bool/enableNotification">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SMALL_ICON"
                android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification_icon" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.TRUSTED_WEB_ACTIVITY_SERVICE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.locationdelegation.PermissionRequestActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**DelegationService.java**

```
import com.google.androidbrowserhelper.locationdelegation.LocationDelegationExtraCommandHandler;


public class DelegationService extends
        com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.DelegationService {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        
            registerExtraCommandHandler(new LocationDelegationExtraCommandHandler());
        
    }
}
```

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: For my handmade project this happened only on Android 13. I'm not sure what was the cause, but I recreated the project with Bubblewrap and everething works now